# php: brackets/contents from a array?

Tags: php, preg-replace, brackets

If I have a string like this:

```
$str = '[tr]Kapadokya[/tr][en]Cappadocia[/en][de]Test[/de]';
```

I want that

```
$array = array(
'tr' => 'Kapadokya',
'en' => 'Cappadocia',
'de' => 'Test');
```

How do I do this?

Comment: Please keep in mind that the SO-community in general likes to see a bit more effort before asking a question: What did you try to solve the problem? Did you do some basic research? ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a few assumptions about the actual syntax of your BBCode-ish string the following [(pc) regular expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_Compatible_Regular_Expressions) might suffice.

```
<?php
$str = '[tr]Kapadokya[/tr][en]Cappadocia[/en][de]Test[/de]';

$pattern = '!
    \[
        ([^\]]+)
    \]
    (.+)
    \[
      /
        \\1
    \]
!x';

/* alternative, probably better expression (see comments)
$pattern = '!
    \[            (?# pattern start with a literal [ )
        ([^\]]+)  (?# is followed by one or more characters other than ] - those characters are grouped as subcapture #1, see below )
    \]            (?# is followed by one literal ] )
    (             (?# capture all following characters )
      [^[]+       (?# as long as not a literal ] is encountered - there must be at least one such character )
    )
    \[            (?# pattern ends with a literal [ and )
      /           (?# literal / )
      \1          (?# the same characters as between the opening [...] - that's subcapture #1  )
    \]            (?# and finally a literal ] )
!x';     // the x modifier allows us to make the pattern easier to read because literal white spaces are ignored
*/

preg_match_all($pattern, $str, $matches);
var_export($matches);
```

prints

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => '[tr]Kapadokya[/tr]',
    1 => '[en]Cappadocia[/en]',
    2 => '[de]Test[/de]',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    0 => 'tr',
    1 => 'en',
    2 => 'de',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    0 => 'Kapadokya',
    1 => 'Cappadocia',
    2 => 'Test',
  ),
)
```

see also: http://docs.php.net/pcre

Comment: There is no need to double escape the backreference and you should change `.+` to `[^[]+` or at least `.+?` to limit the backtracking (and if several translations are on the same line).

Comment: a) yes, probably; I never would though because I was raised a C-developer where it was (back in those days, *sigh* :D) an error. But you're right. b) no, I don't want to; that's the liberty I put into "a few assumptions" ;-) But yes, using `[^[]+` can _easily_ be considered better.

Comment: We have indeed few informations about the exact syntax of this bbcode-like, but it seems to be consecutives translations of the same term, so I assumed, my turn, that these tags can't contain nested tags, but the future is the door to all possible.

Comment: And your points are completely valid and therefore incoporated into the answer.